Why isn't a batch created if you don't put the Batch block immediately after the Source block?
I tried to put the Batch block at the beginning (immediately after the Source block and, of course, everything worked)but I need the product to pass through the conveyor and only then be converted into a batch. Do I understand correctly that a batch can only be created after the Source block?


Do I understand correctly that a batch can only be created after the Source block?

No. It can be put anywhere, if you use it correctly.

Could you please explain what you mean by "use it correctly"?
I do not understand why after the first agent enters the Batch block, the agents who followed it cannot get there, while there are no errors in the console.
I'm new to AnyLogic, so would be very grateful for an explanation.

If an agent enters a Batch block, others also enter it until it is time to output a new batch. Did you read the help: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/batch.html#batch
There is a queue inside the Batch block.
Your issue is likely something else. Pls first mark this as answered (as it answers your original question). Then, open a new issue with your actual question, see some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
